# Horizontal alignment of containers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

want horizontal alignment of div. Container from left (with blue border) may have a fixed height. Other to containers (with red border) should be aligned horizontally to the left blue container regardless of blue container's height.

```css
.cursor-pointer {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.equal-height {
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
}

.border-red {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #FF0000;
}
.border-blue {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #2E2EB8;
}
.border-green {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #00CC00;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row border-green equal-height">
        <div class="col-xs-6 border-blue">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Z</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    a<br>
                    a<br>
                    a<br>
                    a<br>
                    a<br>
                    a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="border-red">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">X</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        c<br>
                        c<br>
                        c<br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="border-red">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Y</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using bootstrap you need to wrap your grid in a container element.

Columns have padding by themselves that's why you see padding on second column.
If you don't want it you can remove it. ( I did it inline but I suggest you to add some class like like .noRPad )

You might wonder why doesn't blue element have padding? It does but you actually gave your border-blue class to the column itself. If you moved it inside of column you would see the same result you have with the border-red elements.

Here's a demonstration of that https://jsfiddle.net/fegm9pc4/

And here's a demonstration of padding removed from columns by adding class .noPad https://jsfiddle.net/fegm9pc4/2/

**Example:**

```css
.cursor-pointer {
cursor: pointer;
}

.equal-height {
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
}

.border-red {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #FF0000;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.border-blue {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #2E2EB8;
}
.border-green {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #00CC00;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row border-green equal-height">
    <div class="col-xs-6 border-blue">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Z</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                a<br>
                a<br>
                a<br>
                a<br>
                a<br>
                a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6" style="display: flex;flex-direction: column;padding-right: 0;">
        <div class="border-red">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">X</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    c<br>
                    c<br>
                    c<br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="border-red">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Y</div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes I can afford flex as I'm giving support IE 10+. Yes, I'm talking about height. Cumulative height of right red containers should be equal to left blue container, vice-versa.

Comment: divs look well aligned. Can I align containers inside also? I think there's padding, right?

Comment: How would you like to align them? I think you might have a misuderstanding of what alignment is. If you could draw a picture of how it should look like that would be good.

Comment: currently the blue and red div borders are aligned at top and bottom. Wanted to align panels' top and bottom. top of the panels are already aligned. look at the bottom left and bottom right panels. Their bottoms are not aligned. That's the point.

Comment: That comes from col-xs-6 class. Which carries padding styling with itself. I guess you can remove padding right and it will fill the rest of the container. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112360/discussion-between-fatcop-and-paran0a).